New laptop connects to distant router over close one
My home network consists of a gateway (modem and router in one) in my basement and a wireless router configured as an access point in my office connected to the gateway via a wired connection. Both the gateway and router are WiFi 6 and are set up with the same SSID and password for 5Ghz. Until now this has worked well as devices automatically switch to the one with the stronger signal as I move around the house. When I had different SSIDs I found devices would hang on to the connected SSID too long, until the signal was so weak it had to switch.
My employer recently gave me a new laptop and for some reason it will only connect to the gateway in the basement even though I'm using it in my office. When not connected it shows the SSID with 4 bars, but as soon as I connect it drops to 1 bar and running a speed test gives very poor results. I even tried rebooting the gateway to force it to connect to the office router, which it did, until the gateway finished booting at which point it went back to the gateway.
Other than going back to different SSIDs for the gateway and router so I can force it to connect to one or the other, is there any way to get this laptop to connect to the office router three feet away instead of the gateway that's two floors and 40 feet away?

I figured it out. The gateway was configured to use WPA2/WPA3 while the router was configured to use WPA2/WPA. Once I updated the router to use WPA3/WPA2 the laptop connected to it. It appears it was preferring the connection with the higher level of security over the connection with the stronger signal.
